# Android v7-sdk21 Hamburger Navigation Drawer toggle without show back arrow

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-navigation

It is possible to just show the Android default hamburger navigation drawer without change to back arrow feature?

Comment: Whats your progress till now..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation you're referring to is handled in the `onDrawerOpened()`, `onDrawerClosed()`, and `onDrawerSlide()` methods of the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` class. To disable it, simply override those methods without calling through to the `super`'s methods. For example:

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(...) {
    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

    }
};
```